# read.json not working in spark 2.1 as expected

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was using spark 1.3 to read a JSON stream using .jsonRDD. However, when I was using this with 2.1 it did not work as it is deprecated. The updated version is read.json(). However read.json does not seem to work and gives me an error

```
u"cannot resolve '`availableDocks`' given input columns: [];
```

The code is given below

```
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)
streams=ssc.textFileStream('s3://realtime-nyc-bike')
def getSparkSessionInstance(sparkConf):
    if ("sparkSessionSingletonInstance" not in globals()):
        globals()["sparkSessionSingletonInstance"] = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .config(conf=sparkConf) \
            .getOrCreate()
    return globals()["sparkSessionSingletonInstance"]

def process(time, rdd):
    print("========= %s =========" % str(time))
    try:
        # Get the singleton instance of SparkSession
        spark = getSparkSessionInstance(rdd.context.getConf())

        # Convert RDD[String] to RDD[Row] to DataFrame
        df = spark.read.json(rdd)

        # Creates a temporary view using the DataFrame

        df.createOrReplaceTempView("station_data")
        results=spark.sql("select stationName from station_data where availableDocks > 20") 
        results.show()
```

The json is a valid format and verified. Is there a way to specify columns for a json. This was working fine on 1.3 using jsonRDD. The json data can be obtained from https://feeds.citibikenyc.com/stations/stations.json where i am using only the stationBeanList.

Comment: what does `df.printSchema()` after ` df = spark.read.json(rdd)` looks like?

Comment: i dont believe it has a schema

Comment: That is issue then. Because if it doesnt have schema , then how it suppose create tempview and may be thats why sql statement is failing bcoz it doesnt know what that column is..

Comment: Yes but as it is a json format should the schema not be inferred?

Comment: yes, it should and thats why you should look inspect how you are getting the rdd. Its is possible that sometime that rdd might be empty. In such cases, your dataframe processing should not kick in otherwise problems like above will occur

Comment: You are right the stream was being passed empty. I have set the bucket properly but the stream is still being passed empty. Not sure why